# One random child get a 008b error (segmentation fault, SIGSEGV). How to debug?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, fork, child-process

I'm creating 100 child with fork() that synchronize themselves using semaphores for a limited amount of time (10 secs), then they got killed by a kill() in the signal handler. I keep getting a SIGSEGV exit status from one of this child (it could be the 54th as the 99th) that interrupts all the child after him untill the SIGALRM and the kill() due to time expired. I'm trying to use GDB to track the child with the command `set follow-fork-mode child` but it happens randomly so I don't know which one to follow nor where it get the segmentation fault error.
I'm new to GDB so please try to be very clear. Thank you.

Comment: Are all your 100 children doing the same thing?

Comment: I don't think a debugger will be a good tool for troubleshooting something like this. I would use logging.

Comment: @PratikSampat a Child gains the LOCK, interact with a shared memory to create "a group of children" and then UNLOCK. Another Child Gains the LOCK... and so on for 10 seconds.

Comment: What about postmortem debugging? (`gdb the-executable the-coredump-file`)

Comment: @PSkocik I checked for the coredump file but it is erased after the 10 secs i think, or anyway, beacuse the child "crashes" randomly I can't/DON'T KNOW how to check that file nor the SIGSEGV error

Comment: Why would it get erased after 10s? Coredumps on Linux normally stick around.

Comment: @PSkocik That's why I caps "Don't know", because I'm not used to Linux and still learning how to properly work with it :D